# Second Order Partial Derivative of functions

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I am required to show that all partial order derivatives of the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{xy(x^2-y^3)}{x^3+y^3} & \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
0 & \text{if } (x,y) = (0,0) 
\end{cases}
$$

exists everywhere, but the mixed second order partial derivatives are unequal at the $(0,0).$

I tried to solve it as follows:
find $D_{11}$, $D_{12}$, $D_{21}$ and $D_{22}$ of the function, and thereafter try to show that at $D_{12}(0,0) \neq D_{21}(0,0).$

With some tedious calculations 
$$
D_{12} = \frac{x^6+9x^4y^2-9x^2y^4-y^6}{(x^2+y^2)^3} \\ 
D_{21} = \frac{9x^4y^2-y^6-9y^4x^2+x^6}{(x^2+y^2)^3}
$$

My doubts are:

1. At $(0,0)$ both $D_{12}$ and $D_{21}$ work out to $0$ only so I am going wrong somewhere.
2. I am getting confused with initial condition $f(x,y) = 0$ if $(x,y) = (0,0).$ Because if $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and we need to show inequality at $(0,0)$, isn't the function $0$ and hence both $D_{12}$ and $D_{21}$, therefore $0$, $0$?
3. Is there any good textbook/link on web where I can get more practice problems similar to this?

Request guide to understand the problem

Comment: I did see an almost similar question for first order partial derivative on this forum... but I have still not understood it

Answer (score 1):

First, $f$ is a quotient of polynomials with no singularities except at $(0,0)$, so it is smooth everywhere except at $(0,0)$.

Second, this only makes sense if you use the (more) "real" definition of the derivative, using limits, i.e:
$$
\partial_x g(x,y)|_{a,b} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} (g(a+h,b) - g(a,b))/h
$$
Note that your expressions are, literally, identical: $D_{12}=D_{21}$, so you would need some other information to see they are not the same.

We are looking at:
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{xy(x^2-y^3)}{x^3 + y^3}
$$

Here, just use the definition starting from the first derivatives:
$$
f_x=\partial_x f = \frac{ x^2(3+2x)y^4 - y^7 }{(x^3 + y^3)^2}
\;\;\;\;\&\;\;\;\;
f_y=\partial_y f = \frac{x^6 - 2x^3(1+2x)y^3 - xy^6}{(x^3 + y^3)^2}
$$
Then, we can do:
\begin{align}
\partial_{x}f_y|_{0,0}
&= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} (f_y(0+h,0) - f_y(0,0))/h \\
&= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} f_y(h,0)/h \\
&= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{h^6}{h^6}\frac{1}{h} \\ &= \infty
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\partial_{y}f_x|_{0,0}
&= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} (f_x(0,0+h) - f_x(0,0))/h \\
&= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} f_x(0,h)/h \\
&= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{ -h^7 }{h^6} \\ 
&= 0
\end{align}
which shows that $\partial_{xy}f(0,0)\ne\partial_{yx}f(0,0)$. Hopefully I didn't make any mistakes!